# Recommendation for good source of Robotic Components

Tags: mobile-robot, motor

Im looking for a good source for robotic components like sheel/tracked robot chasis, motors, sensors, communication and mechanics. I thought about using raspberry and arduino as platforms for automation, is that an good idea? Im asking as i dont know yet much about the motors/drives uses for powering robots.

Thanks!

Uli

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* Ulrich Beck, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some reputable sources of getting robot parts are:

- [Adafruit](http://www.adafruit.com/category/227)
- [Robotshop](http://www.robotshop.com/)
- [Robot Marketplace](http://www.robotmarketplace.com/store.html)
- [Pololu](https://www.pololu.com/)
- [Jameco Robot Store](http://www.jameco.com/Jameco/robot/robotstore.html)
- [Trossen Robotics](http://www.trossenrobotics.com/robot-parts.aspx)
- [HobbyKing](http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/index.asp)

If you need to get specialized electronic parts (e.g. microcontrollers, transistors, etc.) then you might want to look into:

- [Digi-Key](http://www.digikey.com/)
- [Jameco](http://www.jameco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/StoreCatalogDisplay?storeId=10001&catalogId=10001&langId=-1&rfr=1)
- [Newark Element 14](http://www.newark.com/)

These are only to name a few to help you get started.

Comment: These are all very good suggestions. Another really good one you didn't mention: [Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/).

Answer (score 0):

[Radioshack](http://www.radioshack.com) is good, although it recently went bankrupt, but a few of their stores are still around. [Texas Instruments](http://www.ti.com) is a good source, it's out of Texas and has nearly any electronic components needed.